# Weighted Interval Scheduling

Tags: algorithms, math-software

I am software programmer looking for Useful Algorithms And Mathematical Explanations & Theorems for Weighted Interval Scheduling Problem.

Please Provide Me Some Useful Information on this.

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna look up the book "Planning and Scheduling in Manufacturing and Services" by Michael L. Pinedo. I've used it myself and I found it to be a comprehensive, well-written book. For a preview, check out [this Google Books preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=pllNcbTzb3UC&pg=PA207&dq=M.+Pinedo%3a+Planning+and+Scheduling&hl=nl&ei=6djGTaanHpDtOduUsPYB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CFMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=M.%20Pinedo%3A%20Planning%20and%20Scheduling&f=false).

You're probably interested in chapter 9, which deals with interval scheduling, reservations and timetabling.